# Netgear Prosafe GSM7248 Console problems

Tags: switch, console, rs232, managed

Hey all this is my first time dealing with a managed switch and i seem to be having issues with trying to log into the RS232 console on it.

First thing i did was reset it back to factory defaults (i bought it on ebay). After doing that i connected my FTDI USB to rs232 to it and made sure all drivers were installed. It came up as COM11 in my device manager.

Using Putty or Tera Term and connecting to it as it says too in the PDF:

> PC with Static IP Address: When the PC is in this mode, the switch
>   must also be assigned a static IP address. To assign a static IP
>   Address, access the switch from the serial console port as follows:
>
> 1. Connect a console to the switch. Using the null-modem cable supplied with the switch, connect a VT100/ANSI terminal or a
>      workstation to the switch port labeled Console.
> 2. Start a terminal emulation program (TEP). a. Start TEP using the appropriate method for your operating system: • Windows users can use
>      HyperTerminal. • Windows Vista users should download a TEP from the
>      Internet. • Macintosh users can use ZTerm. • UNIX users can use a
>      terminal emulator such as TIP.
>
> b. Configure the TEP to use the following settings (they are written
>   below the connector on the switch front panel): • Baud rate: 9,600 bps
>   • Data bits: 8 • Parity: none • Stop bit: 1 • Flow control: none
>
> c. At the command prompt User:, login to the switch using the user
>   name admin, then press Enter. At the password prompt, press Enter
>   again (no password is needed for initial configuration).
>
> d. At the next command prompt, type ezconfig and press Enter. The
>   ezconfig utility is now running in the switch. Use it to set up your
>   static IP address and subnet mask as shown in the following example.
>   Make sure that the selected switch IP address is in the same subnet as
>   that of the PCs.

All i see in the terminal window is a blinking cursor.
[image: Terminal screenshot]

I'm not really sure what i am missing. I followed along with each step as it says but i never see the console populate where i can start typing my user name and password. So I am unable to setup the switches IP so that i can log into it using the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geeesshh... all because the RS232 to USB was not a Null-modem cable. Rigging it up TO BE a null-modem cable, oddly, made it work just fine.
[image]
[image]